# Import and render React components based on names provided by a database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React components for my SVG icons eg:

```
const ErrorIcon = props => {
  const { color } = props;
  return (
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 90.206 94.8">
        <path
          d="M55.7 82.9v2.8c0 2.2-1."
          fill={color}
        />
      </svg>
  );
};
```

I have a page where I need to apply icons based on the name provided by an ID that comes from the database

```
const data = [{ id: "dog", name: "A Dog" }, { id: "cat", name: "A kitty"}]
```

If I was styling based on class names then I could render the ID like so:

```
 const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        data.map(item=>{
            return(<li className={`Icon Icon--${item.id}`} key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
        })
      }
     </ul>
  );
};
```

And style with:

```
.Icon--dog {
  background: url(dog.jpg);
}
```

Is there a way I can do this while keeping my icons as React components?

Comment: Is `"dog"` really an id (unique?) or is it more like a type? If you are trying to dynamically render an icon component depending on a certain type that is easy to achieve by mapping the types to their respective components.

Comment: Yes it really is an ID and it is unique.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Does my answer solve what you where asking for? I don't see how ids can be used in class names to style something. You would basically have to write a css class for every row in your database.

Comment: Imagine I have web pages for different pets, so one for dogs, one for cats, etc. The page url comes from a field in the database, eg for a Tasmanian Devil the field would be "tasmanian-devil".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mapping of types to components like this:

```
import {DogIcon, CatIcon} from './icons';

const iconMap = {
    dog: DogIcon,
    cat: CatIcon,
};
```

and then render it like this:

```
const MyComponent ({data}) => (
    <ul>
        {data.map(item => {
            const Icon = iconMap[item.type];
            return (
                <li>
                    <Icon />
                    {item.name}
                </li>
            );
        })}
    </ul>
);
```

[image: Edit x3ooqjyoyo]